# Law of Cosines Angle Formula

Tags: trigonometry

So, I understand that the law of cosines is: $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2\ a\ b \ cos(C)$

So how come, when calculating for an angle, the $-2\ a\ b$ becomes a positive divisor instead of staying negative?

i.e, why is it positive here: $\theta = arcos(\frac{a^2 \ +\ b^2 \ -\ c^2}{2\ a\ b})$

I'm confused because, am not dividing both sides by $-2 \ a \ b$ hence the second formula above to get the angle, it would remain a negative ($-2 \ a \ b$ ) instead of ($2 \ a \ b$ )?

What I am confused about is the exact process of how the sign changed to positive in the formula. nothing else.

Comment: I don't understand what is your doubt see my answer also you have written the wrong expression in the last line it should be c^2 instead of a^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$c^2 = b^2 +a^2  - 2\ a\ b \ cos(\theta)$$
you can also write it as
$$ 2\ a\ b \ cos(\theta) = b^2 + a^2-c^2 $$
thus $$ cos(\theta) = \frac{b^2 + a^2-c^2}{2 a b}  $$
thus $$\theta = arcos(\frac{a^2 \ +\ b^2 \ -\ c^2}{2\ a\ b})$$

Comment: Right except the first equation is wrong because it should be $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta$, or it could also be $a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \cos \theta$.

Comment: yeah you are correct I made the mistake

Comment: What I'm confused about is how the divisor `2*a*b` for calculating the angle became positive. everytime I do it, it reains `-2*a*b`.

Comment: also, you are changing the sides so when you first write it was on left side now it is going on the right side thus sign changes

Comment: Yes, I know it is correct, however, I am not intuitively understanding how it got there from `c^2=a^2+b^2−2 a b cos(C)`. When I rearange the forumla, I keep getting `theta = arcos((a^2 + b^2 - c^2)/(-2*a*b))`

Comment: But are you not dividing `-2*a*b` on each side? How would the sign change?

Comment: because you are changing the side also read my answer  carefully hopefully you  will get the logic

Comment: I see. Maybe I'm just confusing some basic rule. I always thought dividing by a negative still remains a negative unless cancelled out by another negative. 

When you say "changing the side", am I really dividing each side by `-2*a*b` or is something else happening?

Comment: let's do it your way then $c^2-b^2 -a^2 =   - 2\ a\ b \ cos(\theta)$ agree with this
now multiply each side by -1    equation becomes $b^2+ a^2-c^2 =   2\ a\ b \ cos(\theta)$ agree with this ?

now divde each side by 2ab  it's that simple

Comment: Okay. I think I understand. Thank you

Comment: @JDoe You’re not “dividing by a negative.” You first move the $2ab\cos(C)$ to the other side of the equal sign, which changes it from negative to positive, i.e., you *add* $2ab\cos(C)$ to both sides of the equation.